# Apparent diameter of Sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics

The light ray grazing the surface of a massive sphere of coordinate radius $r >
\frac{3 GM}{c^2}$ will arrive at infinity with the impact parameter $b=r\left (\frac{1}{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}\right)^{1/2}$.

Now how can we estimate the extent by which the apparent diameter of the Sun with mass $M = 2 × 10^{30} kg$
and radius $R= 7 × 10^8 m$ exceeds the coordinate diameter?

Answer (score 1):

You have your answer in the question. The apparent radius of the Sun, as viewed from far away, is increased by a factor of $(1 - r_s/r)^{-1/2} \simeq 1.0000021$.

Yes, the answer is modified very slightly because the Sun is not "very" far away and thus we do not see a whole hemisphere from Earth, but the correction factor above as applied to the Euclidean angular diameter of the Sun will still work to very high precision.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula $\theta = \dfrac{4GM}{c^2}$ for the angle of deflection of light in the gravitational field of a point mass.